# check box selection not shown when submitting html form

Tags: html, forms

I have below html code

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <span class="anchor">Select Fruits</span>
  <ul class="items">
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Apple </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Orange</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Grapes </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Berry </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Mango </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Banana </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" />Tomato</li>
  </ul>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Output is shown as below in html

[image]

When I submit the form fruit selection options are not shown. I am getting output as cars=volvo. How to get check box selection?  What is the bug?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Where are the name attributes? How is the form supposed to know what the checkbox maps to if you do not give it the name? That is why it is not there. You should also use a label element to make it easier to interact with the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

When creating forms, every form input requires a "name" attribute. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Type your name here">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a name  and a value attribute on every checkbox  like so :

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apple" />
```

and so on...

$_GET['fruit'] will return an array consisting of all the values of the checkboxes that were checked.